# Selenium SelectBox Performance

Tags: python, selenium

Version :

- Python 2.7.6 - 32 Bits
- Selenium 2.41.0
- Firefox 24.0( Necessary , with the new version FF Hangs)

OS:

- Windows Server 2008 R2, 64 Bits
- 4 vCPU
- 8 GB
- VM With 1:1 Ratio (Private Cloud)

Problems :
I have to crawl aprox: 9000 pages and each page contains 20 selectboxes with around 200 options

I only have to grab the curent value and for that I use :

```
Obj = ElementObj.find_element_by_name(ElementName)
Select(Obj).first_selected_option.get_attribute("value")
```

Now the issue is all about performance it takes 30 seconds to actually go trough one page.
If i try to crawl a page without any selectboxes all goes at a much faster rate (close to 0.4 seconds for page)

So I'm I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: what about pure javascript solution using driver.executeScript(); http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Comment: If it's a simple web page, I wouldn't use Selenium for web scraping it. It is overkill for simple web scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,
So in order to increase your performance it's best to do (if possible)

```
Driver.execute_script("""return document.getElementsByName("%s")[0].value""" % ElementName)
```

This will give you at least 10x Boost Of Performance.

I hope this helps someone !

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is typically slow, it's likely that you aren't doing anything wrong. I've seen it used with many languages, and it doesn't seem to improve noticeably.

Hope that helps :)